# Why can't I install telnet on my macOS catalina with Homebrew?

Tags: catalina, homebrew

Here is the error information:

```bsh
shawnstationdeMacBook-Pro:~ shawnstation$ brew install telnet
==> Downloading https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/remote_cmds/remote_cmds-54.50.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/shawnstation/Library/Caches/Homebrew/telnet-54.50.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/libtelnet/libtelnet-13.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/shawnstation/Library/Caches/Homebrew/telnet--libtelnet-13.tar.gz
==> xcodebuild SYMROOT=build
Last 15 lines from /Users/shawnstation/Library/Logs/Homebrew/telnet/01.xcodebuild:
2020-02-29 03:04:09 +0800

xcodebuild
SYMROOT=build

Build settings from command line:
    SYMROOT = build

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
error: The i386 architecture is deprecated. You should update your ARCHS build setting to remove the i386 architecture. (in target 'libtelnet' from project 'libtelnet')

** BUILD FAILED **


Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!

/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/github.rb:222:in `raise_api_error': curl failed!  (GitHub::Error)
curl: (7) Failed to connect to api.github.com port 443: Connection refused
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/github.rb:180:in `open_api'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/github.rb:294:in `search'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/github.rb:227:in `search_issues'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/github.rb:240:in `issues_for_formula'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:368:in `fetch_issues'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:364:in `issues'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:418:in `dump'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:137:in `rescue in <main>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:29:in `<main>
```

Does anybody know why? thanks a lot.

---

My catalina version is 10.15.2 (19C57) 
Home-brew version is

```bsh
shawnstationdeMacBook-Pro:~ shawnstation$ brew --version
Homebrew 1.6.9
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision fab7d; last commit 2018-07-07)
```

Comment: It says there's an error with connecting to the api.github.com site. You're using a really old version of Homebrew.  Have you tried to update to the most recent version?

Comment: It says right there that the i386 target is not supported.  Very plain error message.  Whether a newer version of Homebrew patches that, I have no idea.  Apple will have no interest in providing a 64-bit version, I'm sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I have updated the homebrew.

Comment: Try `brew doctor` then the recommended steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the brew update first.

```
$ brew update
Fast-forwarded master to origin/master.
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-portable-ruby/portable-ruby-2.6.3.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
################################################################################################################# 100.0%
==> Pouring portable-ruby-2.6.3.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
==> Homebrew has enabled anonymous aggregate formulae and cask analytics.
Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics
No analytics have been recorded yet (or will be during this `brew` run).

==> Homebrew is run entirely by unpaid volunteers. Please consider donating:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#donations
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
```

Then it's ok!

```
$ brew install telnet
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/telnet-63.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring telnet-63.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/telnet/63: 4 files, 138.1KB
```

Comment: tried this and install keep failing

Comment: Nope! It fails. `Warning: No available formula with the name "telnet".`

Answer (score -4):

Installing telnet client on MAC OSX is very easy. You can simply run few commands and then finally run:

```
 brew install telnet
```

First telnet should be installed. You can follow the instruction at [https://brewinstall.org](https://brewinstall.org/how-to-install-telnet-on-mac-using-brew/). 
You can search any mac app that you want to install and get the simple steps to install it.

Comment: That's exactly what the OP is doing here, so I don't see how this is addressing the issue described in the question.